# Unable to copy huge file between NFS folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, rsync, shutil

I'm trying to copy huge file (370 GB) between 2 NFS mounts using linux's `rsync` command in python3:

```
file_src = "/mnt/nfs1/file1.zip"
file_dst = "/mnt2/nfs2/"
subprocess.call(["rsync", "-avu", "--progress", "--whole-file", file_src, file_dst])
```

and after few hours I saw in the logs:

```
373,621,623,053 100%   27.78MB/s    3:33:45 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
```

But when I go to the dst folder, the `file_dst` doesn't exists.

Also the program killed (without logs).

Why the file isn't copied? Is there a better way to copy the file using linux/python?

Answer (score 0):

You made the comment

> But when I go to the dst folder, the file_dst doesn't exists.

That suggest that you are not aware that the form

```
/mnt/nfs2/
```

with the "/" at the end of the remote path tells rsync to expect nfs2 to exist already, and will not create that directory.

If you remove that trailing "/", the directory nfs2 will be created.

rsync probably failed when it filled the transfer buffer to the max limit without being able to empty by writing to disk on the remote.